# SQL Case always uses first Case?

Tags: sql, case

So i have a SQl-Case where it asks if a integer % 3600 is over 10 or not... If not it should
concat() a '0' in Front of it... Same as the other cases, which are slighlty changed... it should represent a time,

It should result in somehting like this:

Int_Sek
00:43:23
09:03:45
34:03:09

But it ends like this:
Int_Sek
0:43:23
4:3:45
23:3:9

So it always uses the first case and i don't know why... Anyone an idea?

```
Select concat(
case 
when Int_Sek / 3600 <= 9 then concat('0', floor(Int_Sek / 3600)) 
when Int_Sek / 3600 >= 10 then floor(Int_Sek / 3600) END, ':', 
case 
when (Int_Sek % 3600) / 60 <= 9 then concat ('0', (Int_Sek % 3600) / 60) 
when (Int_Sek % 3600) / 60 >= 10 then floor((Int_Sek % 3600) / 60) END, ':', 
case 
when ((Int_Sek % 3600) % 60) % 60 <= 9 then concat('0', ((Int_Sek % 3600) % 60) % 60) 
when ((Int_Sek % 3600) % 60 )% 60 >= 10 then floor(((Int_Sek % 3600) % 60) % 60) END) as "Column A",
from Table A
```

Comment: Can you also show the values of `Int_Sek`?

Comment: If you *always* prepend a `0` and take the right-most 2 digits using `RIGHT`, you don't need any conditional logic.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If you are using Postgres, you can simplify that to `to_char(make_interval(secs => int_sek), 'hh24:mi:ss')` or even `make_interval(secs => int_sek)::time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, why not just convert to a `time`?

```
select dateadd(second, int_sek, convert(time, 0))
```

You can format the resulting `time` as a string.

Other databases offer similar functionality.

What is the problem with your code?  Consider your first `case` expression:

```
case when Int_Sek / 3600 <= 9
     then concat('0', floor(Int_Sek / 3600)) 
     when Int_Sek / 3600 >= 10
     then floor(Int_Sek / 3600) 
end,
```

The first `then` returns a string.  The second returns an integer.  What does the overall expression return?  It returns an integer.  So, the leading `'0'` is lost.  There are various ways to address this, but I guess the most canonical would be:

```
case when Int_Sek / 3600 <= 9
     then concat('0', floor(Int_Sek / 3600)) 
     when Int_Sek / 3600 >= 10
     then cast(floor(Int_Sek / 3600) as varchar(255))
end,
```

Note that I might also suggest simplifying it as:

```
concat(case when Int_Sek / 3600 <= 9 then '0' else '' end,
       floor(Int_Sek / 3600), ':',
       . . .
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine... Now it is displayed correclty :D